# How to add a WiFi access point location to Google's database?

Tags: wireless-networking, geolocation

I've seen explanations how to *remove* your wireless access point from Google's location database.

But let's say you wanted to *add* it to the database -- how do you do that?

(Why? For example, the access point is in a high rise out of range of scanners on the street. Plus there's no reliable GPS lock in that location. Therefore being able to get location from Wi-Fi is even more desirable.)

Comment: call up Google & tell 'em to send a Street View van your way.

Comment: @Sathya Ha! But I don't think vans can get Wi-Fi signals 40 floors (~500 feet or ~150 meters) above the street?

Answer (score 0):

Using an Android tablet or phone should do the trick.
 Android devices used in range of your Wi-Fi should report the network's SSID and the access point's MAC along with it's location (based on GPS, nearby cellphone-towers and other Wi-Fis) back to Google. Same for iOS devices and Apple.

Comment: i.e You don;t need to go out of your way to do it. They'll just spy on you anyway ;-)

Comment: Well the catch is my phone hasn't been able to lock on a GPS signal there (inside the building and other tall buildings nearby). That's why I wondered if I could simply type the SSID and coordinates (which I'd just get from Google Maps) into a form somewhere to submit to their database.